# usage and meaning of "à la mode"

Tags: meaning, slang

I found a writing in an old book which was: "Apple pie à la mode".
I was wondering what is the meaning of that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_a_la_Mode

Answer (score 3):

It means 'with ice cream' (though not literally). The term was first used in 'pie à la mode', coined by John Gieriet in 1885.

Comment: Good information.

Comment: BTW, since this was coined in English, the (American) pronunciation is /payælə'mod/. Definitely not French.

Comment: Well, that's debatable - it was coined by a French speaking Swiss...

Comment: @ElendilTheTall: And *this* is why we use hyphens! It was coined by a French-speaking Swiss, or a Swiss speaking French, but not a French speaking Swiss ;-)

Answer (score 2):

*À la mode* means *served with ice cream* in this context.

EDIT: The expression *à la mode* is French for "in the current fashion."

Comment: is it in french?

Comment: Yes, it's borrowed from French. The expression _à la mode_ actually means _in the current fashion_.